# Работа с API используя XML

Tags: php, xml

Всем добрый день!

Работаю с API платежной сис-мы, где есть проверка статуса платежа. То есть на мой сервер каждые 5 минут отправляется POST запрос, который я обрабатываю и вношу изменения в свою базу. Так вот, задача такова, чтобы дать серверу платежной системы ответ, о том, что все, платёж завершен. Для этого у них есть такой способ реализации:

```
  Сообщение считается доставленным, если страница обрабатывающая уведомление, вернет

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><result>0</result></response>
и код HTTP ответа 200, иначе оповещение о выполненном платеже будет повторяться.
```

Делаю это вот так:

```
$orderID = $_POST['orderId'];
$status = $_POST['paymentStatus'];

if($status == 1)
{
    global $DB;
    $DB->Query("UPDATE `pay_inout` SET `status` = 1 WHERE orderid = '$orderID'");

    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><result>0</result></response>';


}
if($status == 0 || 2)
{
    global $DB;
    $DB->Query("UPDATE `pay_inout` SET `status` = '$status' WHERE orderid = '$orderID'");

    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><result>0</result></response>';

}
```

Вроде как все должно работать, но нет. Сервер платежной системы продолжает отсылать POST запросы и считает, что платеж еще не обработан моей системой.

Проверял через сторонний сервис, эта страничка отдает HTTP 200, значит дело именно в XML.

Comment: Откуда вообще вы берете конструкции `$status == 0 || 2`? По русски как она читается - "Если статус равен нулю или два". Где во второй части написано "статус равен двум"?

Comment: Ну смотрите, 
Если статус приходит 1, то делаем запрос в БД и ставим 1.

Если статус приходит 0 или 2, то записываем в бд тот статус, который пришел. 
Это просто уж я наколхозил вот так, можно было просто else и запрос.

Comment: На второе условие вообще нет смысла смотреть. Потому что у меня статус приходит именно 1. И в БД он меняет на единицу) 
Просто эти нотификации не останавливаются, они не получают нужный для их остановки XML.

Comment: Я понимаю что вы хотите сделать. Вы делаете это __неправильно__. `$status == 0 || $status == 2` вот как правильно.

Comment: А, благодарю! Действительно. 
А насчет XML есть мысли?

Comment: Вы понимаете что число `2` оно всегда тру? И даже если у вас статус = 1, то второе условие также отдает свой xml.

Comment: @u_mulder , к сожалению не понимаю. я новичок еще в php. просто у меня в голове вот так:
$status = 1; => значит сработает первое условие,
а если $status = 0 || $status = 2 => то сработает второе условие

Comment: Ну и с исправленным `if` теперь какая-то проблема есть?

Comment: @u_mulder , спасибо большое за помощь! Действительно ведь, теперь всё работает исправно) Не думал, что такой косяк в условие так может повлиять)